How to build this "Tiny C Runtime Library" a VS 2008 project in VS 2022?
I am trying to build an old VS2008 VC++ opensource project in VS2022 but getting compilation errors.
Here is the project link -> Tiny C Runtime Library.
Could someone offer guidance or suggest a solution.
Here is the pic that contains the compilation errors while building in VS2022 ->
